# integrating facebook popout chat into website

Tags: php, facebook, chat, facebook-chat

I want to integrate facebook popout chat into my website's chat bar so users can view their facebook chat from my website. I have integrated it by using the popout url but when it opens up just a blank box appears with facebook logo and just a link to facebook and won't let users chat from my site.

```
http://www.cometchat.com/support/uploads/monthly_01_2011/post-3589-12949465773284_thumb.jpg
```

Thanks for any input

David

Comment: That explains it, do you know how i can implement Jabber (something like candy) into my chat bar, are there any clients similar to meebo i could integrate?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently Facebook's popout chat client can not be integrated into external sites: it relies on certain features in the Facebook client website to support it (the same way that Google's popout chat in GMail can't be hosted on third party sites). You won't be able to get this done using the default Facebook chat implementation.

What you can do (which is significantly more complex) is host your own Jabber browser client that connects back to Facebook chat. Something like [Candy](http://amiadogroup.github.com/candy/) might be able to do it with some additional (significant) modifications.